# Apple portuguese keyboard and compatibility with various Linux distributions

Tags: linux, keyboard, vmware-player, linux-distributions

Certain Linux distributions, Ubuntu and Mandriva that I know of, have the proper keyboard mapping for me run them inside VMWare Fusion without having to do any special keyboard configuration with my portuguese keyboard. Others, Debian as an example, have imperfect keyboard mappings out of the box that cause me to lose things like the '@' key and certain other symbols.

I would like to run other Linux distributions inside VMWare, but I don't like having to mess around with the keyboard mappings. Where do I find the files in either Ubuntu or Mandriva to transfer them over for use in other distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be very useful i think:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=188761&highlight=layout

Comment: While does does seem to containt he answer **at this moment** any external link could change or disappear. Could you add the relevant part of the answer to your post?